# How to replace emojis with their text descriptions in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, emoji

I have a Google Spreadsheets table with emojis:

[image: sample table]

I would like to add their text descriptions to the second column. I've created the mapping table on the second sheet:

[image]

Now I am trying to understand how to replace several symbols in one cell with text descriptions (`VLOOKUP` doesn't help here).

Comment: Do you have a list of emojis descriptions?

Comment: @Martí, yes - as additional sheet (column A - emoji, column B - description)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B2:B," "),Description!A:B,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: So easy, many thanks! The following formula worked for me
`=JOIN(" ";ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(SPLIT(B2;" ");A:B;2;FALSE)))`